# PHPSESSID: Session Cookie Does Not Contain the "Secure" Attribute

Tags: cookie, magento2.3.0, https, secure

In m1 we could just override isSecure from `Mage_Core_Model_Cookie` model, method:

```
public function isSecure()
{ 
    return $this->_getRequest()->isSecure(); 
}
```

How can we accomplish this in m2?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this may be one of the dumbest things i've over looked before but I had it all correctly set in Admin > Stores > Configuration > Web : Secure and unsecure base URL's for "Default Config" although in Store View: i needed to change the scope to "Default Store View" and set the https there as well. Furthermore, you'll need to do the same for every store view.

Answer (score 1):

You probably looking for **class SecurityInfo** which implements **SecurityInfoInterface** in file path;

> Magento\Framework\Url\SecurityInfo.php

Comment: I see the public function that you're speaking of inside that file.    public function isSecure($url)  << is this what i need to edit to get the check mark for secure?? See above picture that i've added. Thanks in advance. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this method @fmsthrid

Comment: hello @fmsthird i'm still looking for help here.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you are accessing your site over HTTPS and you have no custom code modifying the cookie secure values, you shouldn't need to modify the core code to serve `PHPSESSIONID` as secure. As its default behavior

See for example: 
https://barberblades.co.uk
https://www.bathroomsupastore.com

---

I have not tested this but I believe the Magento 2 equivalent of the code you posted, to force all cookies to the request type would be within:

```
magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/CookieMetadata.php->getSecure()
magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/SensitiveCookieMetadata.php->getSecure()
```

You could create a Magento Plugin that fires before that method is called returning the result of `Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface->isSecure()`

Comment: I'd rather not modify core code and i kind of like the idea of creating a plugin. I know plugins are rather new in m2 and i've never created one. I'll look into this idea more. But you're saying i could edit those core files too, correct? Additionally, I'm got seeing the getSecure method in those files... i see this method:     public function setSecure($secure)
    {
        return $this->set(self::KEY_SECURE, $secure);
    }

Comment: Actually, i'm sorrry, i see getSecure in SensitiveCookieMetadata.php but not that first file. @Sam

Comment: My bad I've updated my answer to point to the correct file now, the getSecure method in the first file inherited from CookieMetadata. And correct, you could technically modify the core files although I would avoid that since your updates would be lost when you update Magento (also can be a pain to debug if you forget about it). Instead, I would recommend using a custom module with a preference to overwrite the class which would persist across core version updates. See https://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/

Comment: no worries...I've done some overriding of classes before but i'll read the inchoo article. So if i do want to make the core changes.. i need to change both files you've listed? And i'm assuming i'm just going to change the return to     return $this->_getRequest()->isSecure(); 
???

Comment: For SensitiveCookieMetadata you could but would need to inject the request object into CookieMetadata. Then since you modified the constructor in CookieMetadata you would need to rebuild the DI stuff (i use setup:upgrade for that) Example below from Magento Community v2.2.8

https://gist.github.com/SamJUK/50e3404e9008b0a42dcfae007613f046

Comment: Nice, i see what you mean. You think that will work? I'll give it a shot and if it doesn't i'll go about overriding the classes. But i also like the idea of using a plugin/interceptor. Thanks for helping me out @Sam.

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind is, that this sets the cookie secure state based on whether you land on http/https. With redirecting http to https is this done through the option in Magento backend or server config? Potentially if this is done through the Magento backend option, if the user visits http://example.com Magento may create the session cookie and set it to insecure before redirecting the user to the https site. Best of luck resolving this

Comment: I shouldn't have to worry about that if I'm only using https tho, correct?

Comment: oh .. i get what you're saying.. yeah i guess that could be problematic as well. @Sam

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadata\CookieMetadata, because the name is already in use in /vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/CookieMetadata.php on line 12

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94547/discussion-between-supplement-and-sam).

Comment: Hey @Sam do you think you can still help with the Fatal error thats happening in your code. I would really like to get this resolved. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get whether the URL is secure or not from store manager interface.

Inject `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in your required class and call `isFrontUrlSecure()` on `getStore()` function as following.

```
class ...
{
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(      
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
    }


    public function isFrontUrlSecure()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->isFrontUrlSecure();
    }
```

**EDIT :**

<s>You can override `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadata` 's  `getSecure()` function to accomplish the same and magento 2.</s>

You can also try setting this up from the admin too. Go to

> Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Cookie Settings

and set `Use HTTP Only` to yes.

Comment: thank you for contributing but i don't need to know if it's secure or not secure. I can tell it's not secure by looking at the application in inspect element and verifying it's not secure. Please see image above. I think you misunderstood what i'm saying. I'm trying to figure out how i get that little check on "secure" for PHPSESSID. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I am guessing here that you need to set a secure cookie right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @Vivek Kumar

Comment: Can you help me accomplish that @Vivek Kumar?

Comment: Please check edit

Comment: That will now work just setting to use http only... I need to get a secure cookie on the frontend. @Vivek